# What is proper way to write this linq lambda expression and deal with nulls?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

While this works, I'm fairly certain that there is a more concise (and proper?) way to write this expression.

```
    double currentPopulation = 0.0;
    if (detailmetrics.FirstOrDefault(dm => dm.MetricScopeID == 2 && dm.MetricTypeID == 1 &&
                                           dm.Timeframe.Equals("C")) != null)
    {
         currentPopulation = Convert.ToDouble(
             detailmetrics.FirstOrDefault(dm => dm.MetricScopeID == 2 && dm.MetricTypeID == 1 &&
                                          dm.Timeframe.Equals("C")
             ).MetricValue
         );
    }
```

Comment: If the compile-time type of `dm.Timeframe` is simply `string`, I prefer `dm.Timeframe == "C"` over `dm.Timeframe.Equals("C")`.

Comment: Thank you...the compile time type of dm.Timeframe is indeed a string.  Out of curiousity (and hopefully to learn something), Why do you prefer '==' over .Equals?

Comment: Because it is easier to read (personal opinion). It is for the same reason that I do not do `dm.MetricScopeID.Equals(2)` even if I could. There are other reasons. Using `==` will not give a null reference exception if its left operand is `null`. And using `==` will often complain about accidental wrong comparisons. For example `dm.MetricScopeID.Equals("C")` will compile (but is useless because it compares a number to a string) while `dm.MetricScopeID == "C"` will not compile (informing you that the operation is not allowed).

Comment: You might also want to consider using `double.TryParse` if the value of `MetricValue` might cause `Convert.ToDouble` to throw an exception and you want to handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply

```
double currentPopulation = detailmetrics
    .Where(dm => dm.MetricScopeID == 2 && dm.MetricTypeID == 1 && dm.Timeframe.Equals("C"))
    .Select(a => Convert.ToDouble(a.MetricValue))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Upvoted. Sets `currentPopulation` to `0.0` if no item satisfies the `Where` predicate. I know this is on purpose, but it is different from the original code which does not assign to `currentPopulation` in that case.

Comment: Thank you @Bahrom for your comment.  I edited the original post to show that I am initializing the variable before the condition.

Comment: @MBrianDunson After that edit, this answer is more equivalent to the (edited) code from the question, and in fact Bahrom can re-introduce the `var` they once had since it is appropriate now.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the query result to a temporary variable to avoid evaluating it twice.

```
var dm = detailmetrics.FirstOrDefault(
    dm => dm.MetricScopeID == 2 && dm.MetricTypeID == 1 && dm.Timeframe.Equals("C")
);
if (dm != null) {
    currentPopulation = Convert.ToDouble(dm.MetricValue);
} else {
    currentPopulation = 0.0;
}
```

I don't know the type of `MetricValue`. If it is a `string` for example, you could write it shorter with (instead of the if-statement):

```
currentPopulation = Convert.ToDouble(dm?.MetricValue ?? "0");
```

This means: if `dm` is `null`, take `"0"` (because the expression to the left of `??` yields `null`), otherwise take `dm.MetricValue` and then convert to `double`.

See also:

- [C# : The New and Improved C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) (especially:  Null-Conditional Operator)
- [?? operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten it to:

```
var dm = detailmetrics.FirstOrDefault(dm => dm.MetricScopeID == 2 && dm.MetricTypeID == 1 && dm.Timeframe.Equals("C"));
if (dm != null) {
    currentPopulation = Convert.ToDouble(dm).MetricValue;
}
```

That way you only evaluate the FirstOrDefault once.

Comment: I think you meant `Convert.ToDouble(dm.MetricValue)`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to skin a cat, including (your predicate omitted for brevity):

```
currentPopulation = Convert.ToDouble(
    detailmetrics.FirstOrDefault(predicate)?.MetricValue ?? "0"
    );
```

The above assumes the `MetricValue` is a string that is either null or a valid double, and that you want a 0 result if it is null.

If you don't want to make that assumption, you could write your own "safe" conversion method that handles nulls and invalid values, e.g.:

```
currentPopulation = 
    SafeConvert(detailmetrics.FirstOrDefault(predicate)?.MetricValue);

public double? SafeConvert(string value)
{
    ... your implementation e.g. ...
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return null;
    if (Double.TryParse(value, ... out double result)) return result; 
    ... handle invalid double values ...
}
```